# Count down in ReactJS with update self and customize view

Tags: reactjs, state, countdown

I'm using ReactJS in a project and want create a Countdown with self update and custom view.

I use [react-countdown-clock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-clock). It's very good but i don't know how custom view and it's don't show minutes when minutes is 0. Then I'm using [react-simple-countdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-countdown) that customized with css but when in onEnd() event, update date props with this.state Countdown not restart.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ReactCountdownClock from 'react-countdown-clock';
import CountDown from 'react-simple-countdown';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    var t = new Date();
    t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 15);

    this.state = {
      time: 10,
      date: t,
    }

  }

  change_time() {
    this.setState({
      time: 10,
    })
  }

  change_date() {
    var t = new Date();
    t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 15);

    this.setState({
      date: t,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const messages = {
      days: {
        plural: 'Days',
        singular: 'Day',
      },
      hours: 'Hours',
      mins: 'Min',
      segs: 'Seg',
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ReactCountdownClock seconds={this.state.time}
                             color="#000"
                             size={300}
                             onComplete={this.change_time.bind(this)} />


        <CountDown
            date={this.state.date}
            className="MyCoundown"
            {...messages}
            onEnd={this.change_date.bind(this)} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: ignore those npm packages, they are not mature.  No coverage , no unit-tests....

Answer (score 0):

[react-countdown-clock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-clock) was really just a bit of fun. It serves best of an example of React interacting with canvas (a most probably it's a poor example). It's certainly hard to get it to working in way that suits everyones requirements.

But there is nothing stoping you creating a fork of [react-countdown-clock](https://github.com/pughpugh/react-countdown-clock). You could easily amend it to show minutes (and hours) permanently.

```diff
diff --git a/coffee/react-countdown-clock.coffee b/coffee/react-countdown-clock.coffee
index f41de4d..0c98d5f 100644
--- a/coffee/react-countdown-clock.coffee
+++ b/coffee/react-countdown-clock.coffee
@@ -158,8 +158,8 @@ module.exports = React.createClass
       seconds = "0#{seconds}" if seconds < 10 && minutes >= 1

       timeParts = []
-      timeParts.push hours if hours > 0
-      timeParts.push minutes if minutes > 0
+      timeParts.push hours
+      timeParts.push minutes
       timeParts.push seconds

       timeParts.join ':'
@@ -168,11 +168,7 @@ module.exports = React.createClass

   _fontSize: (timeString) ->
     if @props.fontSize == 'auto'
-      scale = switch timeString.length
-        when 8 then 4 # hh:mm:ss
-        when 5 then 3 # mm:ss
-        else 2        # ss or ss.s
-      size = @_radius / scale
+      size = @_radius / 4
       "#{size}px"
     else
       @props.fontSize
```

Have fun!